# Problem with Replacing special characters in a string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to feed some text to a special pupose parser. The problem with this parser is that it is sensitive to `()[]` characters  and in my sentence in the text have quite a lot of these characters. The manual for the parser suggests that all the `()[]` get replaced with `\( \) \[ \]`. So using `str.replace` i am using to attach `\` to all of those charcaters. I use the code below:

```
a = 'abcdef(1234)'
a.replace('(','\(')
```

however i get this as my output:

```
'abcdef\\(1234)'
```

What is wrong with my code? can anyone provide me a solution to solve this for these characters?

Comment: take a look at : http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape maybe it already what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just how escaped characters (like backslashes) are printed in the REPL. The actual value of the string is as you expected.

```
>>> a = '\('
>>> a
'\\('
>>> print(a)
\(
```

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is wrong with your code. This is Python's way to tell you that the string contains a literal `\`, by showing you that the backslash  has been escaped as `\\`.

That way you can tell if you have two characters, a `\` followed by `(`, or just one character, a escaped bracket `\(`.

You probably expected to see what you see when you do `print 'abcdef\\(1234)'`. What you want is what you already have.

Answer (score 1):

```
suggests that all the ()[] get replaced with \( \) \[ \]
```

As i understand, parser itself make the replacement, so if you input:

```
'abcdef(1234)'
```

output will be:

```
'abcdef\(1234\)'
```

So you have to parse the output to get your original text with:

```
output.replace('\(','(').replace('\)',')')......
```

etc...